# ASP.NET - Requests Queued and Requests Rejected

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, performancecounter

I am running an ASP.NET service. The service starts returning - "Service Unavailable - 503" under high loads.

Previously it was able to cope with these loads, I still am investigating why that is happening now.

I see a high requests rejected rate (via the ASP.NET perf counter) ; however the requests queued rate (via the ASP.NET perf counter) varies from deployment to deployment from 1 to 150. For some deployments that show a high requests rejected rate, I can correlate that to the high requests queued rate. However, for some deployments the requests queued is low - 1-5 but the requests rejected rate is high.

Am I missing something here? Any pointers on how to investigate this issue further?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a peek with a profiler, to see if your getting load in other areas that you weren't before such as syncronous DB and network calls.

Look at newRelic (simple to use) and identify the bottlenecks, so simple code changes may help you get out of your immediate hole.

Moving forward look into making the code base more async (if it isn't already).